# JAXB enum validation

Tags: xml, validation, enums, xsd, jaxb

How can I validate enum values with XSD in JAXB? I would like to throw an error if a bad value was set but missing value is good (`minOccurs = "0"` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("XSD FILE UNDER WEB-INF/classes"));
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using type restriction and enumeration in XML Schema. See this link for [some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256219.aspx)

Take a look at an example type representing gender.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="gender">
  <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="M"/>
  <xsd:enumeration value="F"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

JAXB will generate an enum like this:

```
@XmlType(name = "gender")
@XmlEnum
public enum Gender {

  M,
  F;

  public String value() {
    return name();
  }

  public static Gender fromValue(String v) {
    return valueOf(v);
  }

}
```

and validate your input accordingly. If you use `minOccurs="0"` on the element of a type like this, you should get what you want.

Comment: OK, but JAXB set the enum value to null for bad values, so I cannot see difference between unset value and bad value.

Comment: @nerd I see I failed to get the gist of your question. It's not as much about enums themselves as about how to perform XML validation before unmarshalling the document. I suggest merging our answers or deleting mine and changing the question title to make the solution easier to find for others.